# Why is $S(W)$ a subset of $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$T,S$ are both linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, such that  $TS = ST$.

Why is the following true?

If $W$ is the set of eigenvectors of $T$, then $S(W) ⊆ W$.

Comment: Hint: $TSx=STx=\lambda Sx$ for $x\in W$.

Comment: Are T and S two matrices? Which one is an eigenvector?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Take some $x\in W$, then you want to show that $Sx$ is also an eigenvalue of $T$. So compute what $T$ does to $Sx$ and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. But I am still not sure how do you show what T does to Sx.

Comment: By your assumption, $T(Sx) = TSx = STx = S(Tx)$, so you just need to know what is $Tx$?

Comment: That starts to make sense. So what's Tx?

Comment: Well, you know that $x \in W$, this should give you a clue.